# Prove that the sequence convergences almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables, $X_i$ has distribution given by a density $g(x)= \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2i}} \cdot 1_{[0,1-\frac{1}{2i}]}$.
I'd like to prove that a sequence $\sqrt[2n]{X_1 X_2 \cdot ... \cdot X_n}$ convergences almost surely. $X_i$ is positive almost surely so I can write that:
$$\sqrt[2n]{X_1 X_2 \cdot ... \cdot X_n}=\exp(\ln \sqrt[2n]{X_1 X_2 \cdot ... \cdot X_n})=\exp\left( \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln X_{i} \right)
$$
Random variables $Y_i= \ln(X_i)$ are independent.And if the sequence $$\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln X_{i} 
$$
convergences almost surely then it proves $\sqrt[2n]{X_1 X_2 \cdot ... \cdot X_n}$ convergences, because exponential function is coninuous.
It looks a little bit lika the Strong Large Numbers Law, but of course variables $Y_1,Y_2,..$ have different distributions and thus different expected values.What should I do next? How to settle what is the limit?Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: The random variables are independent. Thankfully, you can rescale them so that they also are identically distributed. Let $Y_i := (1-1/(2i))^{-1} X_i$. Prove that the $Y_i$'s are i.i.d., and identify their distribution. Do your reasoning with the $Y_i$ instead of the $X_i$. Conclude.

Comment: How do I show that the limit doesn't change?

Comment: The limit changes! But I am sure you can find an explicit relation between $(X_1 \cdots X_n)^{1/2n}$ and $(Y_1 \cdots Y_n)^{1/2n}$. If you can find the limit of the later, you can find the limit of the former.

Comment: I suspect $\displaystyle \sqrt[2n]{\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2i}\right)} \to 1$ as $n$ increases and that if $Z$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then $E[\log_e(Z)]=-1$ suggesting an answer to the original question of a limit of $e^{-1/2}\approx 0.60653$

Comment: Elaborating on the suspicion: letting $$a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \ln \sqrt[2n]{ \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2i}\right)}=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2i}\right)$$ we have  that, since $\ln(1-u)\operatorname*{\sim}_{u\to0} u$ and the Harmonic series diverges, $a_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{-H_n}{4n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0^-$, so that $e^{a_n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1^-$. (This is a bit overkill to show the convergence to $1$, but it works.)